# C# converting a decimal to an int safely

Tags: c#, decimal

I am trying to convert a decimal to an integer safely.

Something like

```
public static bool Decimal.TryConvertToInt32(decimal val, out int val)
```

this will return false if it cannot convert to an integer, and true w/ successful output if it can.

This is to avoid catching the OverflowException in decimal.ToInt32 method. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: There are just 2 cases in which that OverflowException is thrown, namely x < int.MinValue and x > int.MaxValue can't you just use an `if`?

Comment: What do you want it to do if it's given, say, 0.5?

Comment: Do you want to round, or truncate the decimal?

Comment: I want to truncate, just as the integer casting currently does. I know I can check against int.min and int.max, was trying to avoid the extra checks since the conversion function does these checks as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here:

```
public static bool TryConvertToInt32(decimal val, out int intval)
{
    if (val > int.MaxValue || val < int.MinValue)
    {
      intval = 0; // assignment required for out parameter
      return false;
    }

    intval = Decimal.ToInt32(val);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Note that you still need to assign to `intval` in the `false` path.

Answer (score 4):

I would write an extension method for class decimal like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool TryConvertToInt32(this decimal decimalValue, out int intValue)
    {
        intValue = 0;
        if ((decimalValue >= int.MinValue) && (decimalValue <= int.MaxValue))
        {
            intValue = Convert.ToInt32(decimalValue);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can use it in that way:

```
if (decimalNumber.TryConvertToInt32(out intValue))
{
    Debug.WriteLine(intValue.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare the decimal against `int.MinValue` and `int.MaxValue` prior to the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using Int32.TryParse(string) ?

Comment: I am not interesting in converting the decimal to a string and then back to a integer. This would cost a lot of performance, and would not directly handle non integer decimals.

Comment: Of course it would. If you do Int32.TryParse("3.14", d) you'd get a False result.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to avoid catching the `OverflowException`? It is there for a reason and you should totally catch it where you call `Decimal.ToInt32()`. Exceptions are used widely throughout the framework and users should catch them. The Try methods can help you around them to make code tighter and cleaner, but where the framework doesn't have a suitable method (`Decimal.TryConvertToInt32()` in this case) catching `OverflowException` is the appropriate thing to do. It is actually more clear than making an extension class or writing your own separate static method (both of those involve writing your own code where the framework is already giving you this functionality).

Comment: Are you suggesting you should *always* catch exceptions, that you should *never* try to avoid them? If so, that's bad advice. Absolutely avoid them when possible (by validating against their known causes, for example), and only catch them when you have the means to actually deal with them. Exceptions are expensive, and they should not be used for control flow.

Comment: You are right and I appreciate the comment. It is up to the developer to determine if this will happen rarely or frequently. In my experience something like OverflowException for converting Decimal.ToInt32 would only happen rarely and an exception handler would work fine to set the result appropriately. But it does depend on the scenario, and again I really appreciate you adding this important note about exception performance.

Comment: Throwing and catching an exception is expensive. Setting up a try/catch block is not, and if the condition that causes the exception _almost never_ happens, it can be cheaper on average than doing the validation [validation that will be repeated in the conversion itself]